# Problems running a java program from the command line interface

Tags: java

I created a java program in Eclipse. When I run the program in Eclipse ("run as -> Java Application") the program runs fine and I have the correct output. However, when I try to run the program in the command line interface I got this error:

> Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`: `HelloWorld` (wrong name: helloworld/HelloWorld)
>   Could not find the main class: HelloWorld. Program will exit.

The class file is in directory bin and I try to run it with the command:

```
java HelloWorld
```

Comment: Is your class in the default package (i.e. no package declaration)?  And when saying `I try to compile it with the command: java HelloWorld`, did you mean running?

Comment: Yes I mean running the project not compiling it.

Comment: My class have a package declaration: package helloworld;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your class is in the package `helloworld` you should run it like this:

```
java helloworld.HelloWorld
```

Also make sure "." is on your classpath.

Comment: It worked. I had to typed it in the directory before the helloworld directory.

Answer (score 1):

> I try to compile it with the command:
>   java HelloWorld

TO compile a java program you should use javac command like

```
javac Helloworld.java
```

Comment: I meant run the file not compiled it as it is already compiled.

Comment: @Victor: Are you providing all required jars in classpath when running it?

Comment: I don't have jars file only the HelloWorld.class and the HelloWorld.java

Comment: @Vector: if your class have package declaration then you should set your class path upto the folder containing helloworld folder instead of helloworld folder.

Comment: And how am I supposed to do that?

Comment: @Victor: by providing class path as -cp argument while running your program.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the directory where your classes are is in the classpath? Typically, in your project directory, the "classes" or "lib" directory.

If you are running from that directory, you could try adding ".".

See the -cp parameter of java runtime executable.